# Error after upgrading Angular 5 to 6 , VSTS build

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, azure-devops, angular6

After upgrading from Angular 5 to 6 i have got it up and running locally. It runns in builds and build --prod . I do have it in an .NET MVC application. However when the build on VSTS goes through it pops up some errors. It says.

```
node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\output\output_ast.d.ts(602,15): Error TS2474: Build:In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.

node_modules\@angular\core\src\render3\interfaces\container.d.ts(35,5): Error TS1169: Build:A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol.

node_modules\@angular\core\src\sanitization\bypass.d.ts(55,14): Error TS2535: Build:Enum type 'BypassType' has members with initializers that are not literals.
```

It is only the build on VSTS that fails and it comes in the process of CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig:

I do run typescript version 2.7.2 and i have set the csproj Typescript version to 2.7 . As Visual studio doesnt have support for 2.9.2 and Angular 6.1.4 doesnt support version 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VSTS build must be using a version of TypeScript older than 2.7, because the error message `A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to a built-in symbol.` does not exist in 2.7 and newer.  It looks like you'll need to use at least 2.7 to compile those type declaration files.  I don't know what controls the TypeScript version of your VSTS build; if you provide more information, I may be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the log said that it used the local typescript version under some microsoft folder. It was version 2.3. i did install up to 2.9.2 and did install it globaly with npm aswell to be sure. It worked thanks allot